# Не совпадают вычисления калькулятора и вычисления программы

Tags: c++, математика, числа

Если на калькуляторе (в моём случае 12-разрядный) высчитать выражение `(1000 / 330) * 200` результат будет `606.06060606`. Я написал программу, которая считает это выражение на компьютере:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    double a = 1000, b = 330, c = 200;
    std::cout << (a / b) * c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Но его результат программа выдаёт неправильный: `606.061`. Как заставить программу высчитывать результаты подобных выражений с точностью до, хотя бы, 6 разрядов (до одной миллионной), чтобы первые шесть цифр после запятой ответа калькулятора чётко совпадали с первыми шестью цифрами после запятой ответа программы? Я пробовал заменить `double` на `float`, на `int`, `long double` - ответ ещё хуже, более худшая точность.

Comment: А почему вы хотите ограничится только 12 цифрами? Почему не 16? 100? 1000? Бесконечность? (В последнем случае ответ: 606 2/33) Насколько точны (верны) входные числа? Не стоит все числа, которые калькулятор печатает в качестве ответа использовать, если входные числа с заведомо худшей точностью известны.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Считает программа со всей возможной точностью...

Вот выводит по умолчанию только 6 знаков. Поясните ей с помощью `setprecision`, что вы хотите видеть вывод более точным.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {

    double a = 1000, b = 330, c = 200;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(12) << (a / b) * c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`cout << setprecision(количество_знаков_после_запятой) << значение ;`

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/199426)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin исправил

Comment: Только вот точность надо залавать ДО вывода значения, а не после.